# Solving probability using Bayes Theorem in Python

Tags: python, math, probability

I have the following question:

> Suppose that a given coin is known to be either a fair coin or else a biased coin such as that described in part a). Although you do not know which it is, you assign a prior probability of 0.8 to the hypothesis that the coin is fair.
>
> The coin is tossed and lands heads. Use Bayes’ theorem to determine the probability that the coin is fair and the probability that the coin is biased* given this observation.
>
> The Theorem is as follows:
>
> P(A|B) = P(B|A) / P(B) * P(A)

The code below is my attempt but I got an error saying I can't use "|" with floats:

```
 print(((0.2|0.8) / 0.2) * 0.8)
```

Comment: The essential problem here is that Python doesn't have a built-in notion of conditional probability, so it won't recognize p(a|b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator "|" is called "binary OR" and it is a binary operator, does not work for floats.

Additionally, P(B|A) is a single probability, read as "Probability of B given condition A happening." It is not the "|" of the single probabilities. In order for Bayes' theorem to work, you need to have 3 inputs, not two.

Check out [Bayes' Theorem on Math is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/bayes-theorem.html)

Comment: So if the prior probability = 0.8 of the fair coin what is the prior probability of the bais coin and what does the formula look like